# Using XDocument to load specific tags into a listbox

Tags: c#, xml, listbox, linq-to-xml, xelement

This is my first time working with XML files and I could use a little help.  I'm also very new to C#. I have created an XML file that contains different word sets based on themes. What I would like to do is load all the words from a specific tag only. However, I do not get an error, it just skips over the code that's supposed to add it to the list box.

Here's a sample of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
        <fantasy>
            <word> 
                <nn>wizard</nn>
                <nns>wizards</nns>
                <type>person</type>
            </word>
            <word> 
                <nn>wand</nn>
                <nns>wands</nns>
                <type>thing</type>
            </word>
            <word> 
                <vb>conjure</vb>
                <vbg>conjuring</vbg>
                <vbd>conjured</vbd>
            </word>
            <word> 
                <nnp>Merlin</nnp>
                <type>person</type>
            </word>
    </fantasy>
    <common>
            <word> 
                <vb>run</vb>
                <vbg>running</vbg>
                <vbd>ran</vbd>
            </word> 
            <word> 
                <nnp>Jeremy</nnp>
                <type>person</type>
            </word>
            <word> 
                <nnp>Dylan</nnp>
                <type>person</type>
            </word>
            <word> 
                <nnp>Darlene</nnp>
                <type>person</type>
            </word>     
            <word> 
                <nnp>Chelsea</nnp>
                <type>person</type>
            </word>
            <word> 
                <jj>beautiful</jj>
                <rb>beautifully</rb>
            </word> 
            <word> 
                <jj>ugly</jj>
            </word> 
            <word> 
                <jj>disgusting</jj>
                <vbn>disgusted</vbn>
                <rb>disgustingly</rb>
                <nn>disgust</nn>                
            </word> 
        </common>
</theme>
```

I'd like to take all the tags labeled  and place them in a listbox.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void menuOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.ShowDialog();
            DocHandler.fileName = open.FileName;
            DocHandler.doc = XDocument.Load(DocHandler.fileName);
            txtText.Text = DocHandler.doc.ToString();

            GetElements();

        }

        public void GetElements()
        {
            foreach (XElement element in DocHandler.doc.Root.Elements())
            {
                if (element.Name.LocalName.Contains("word"))
                {
                    foreach (XElement subelement in element.Elements())
                    {
                        if (subelement.Name.LocalName.Contains("vb"))
                        {
                            listElements.Items.Add(subelement.Value.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class DocHandler
    {
        public static string fileName { get; set; }
        public static XDocument doc;

    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var items = DocHandler.doc.Document.XPathSelectElements("//word/vb")
                          .Select(x => x.Value)
                          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You skipped a level (fantasy and common).

But if you are already using `XDocument` why don't you take advantage of LINQ?

```
var words = DocHandler.doc.Descendants("vb").Select(element => element.Value);
```